# Passing an array to a variable that has a different type in Java

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I have a class InQueue with the following:

```
static Queue<String> q = null;

public InQueue(String[] input){
    q = new LinkedList<String>();

}
public static Queue<String> newInputQueue(String[] inputArray){
    q.addAll(Arrays.asList(inputArray));
    q.add("$");
    return q;
}
```

And I have an array in main that I'm trying to do this:

```
String[] inputArr = {"id", "+", "id", "*", "id"};
InQueue inQueue = new InQueue(inputArr);
```

I want to pass inputArr to inQueue so that my array goes into the queue. But obviously I can't do that because the InQueue constructor doesn't have parameters. Is there a way to do this? I've tried various ways and most of them either don't work, or they return an empty queue.

Comment: "because the InQueue constructor doesn't have parameters" - why are you not creating one?

Comment: I tried that and I still get an empty queue

Comment: Please show your attempt and we might find out what the issue is

Comment: Are u sure about the static Queue<String> q ?

Comment: @BigMike I was told that I would need to do that. No matter what I try I'm still getting an empty queue

Comment: Please show us the code where you get an empty queue.

Comment: You never added the values from the string array to `q`, and `q` being static means you can only ever have a single instance of `q` at any given time. If you made a new empty queue after the fact, it'd overwrite/erase any other queues to begin with. That's why you shouldn't use `static` here, particularly for a (design-wise) instance variable.

Comment: _the InQueue constructor doesn't have parameters_ so why does the posted code show such constructor (`public InQueue(String[] input)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create that constructor yourself:

```
public InQueue(String[] arr){
    q = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
}
```

You should also remove the `static` keyword from both the field `q` as well as the `newInputQueue` method, is there a reason for it?

Comment: I've tried this, and it returns an empty queue. I'm not quite sure why as my input array definitely returns the strings on it's own

Comment: Please post the full code that "returns an empty queue". This constructor takes the array and initializes the field `q` with a LinkedList. If the array has elements, so will the queue.

Comment: I fixed it. I didn't realize you had to use Arrays.asList, and that's why I was getting an empty queue. Thank you for your help, I will mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your class to something like this:

```
private Queue<String> q = null;

private InQueue(){
    q = new LinkedList<String>();    
}
public static InQueue newInputQueue(String[] inputArray){
    InQueue res = new InQueue();
    res.q.addAll(Arrays.asList(inputArray));
    res.q.add("$");
    return res;
}
```

What are the main differences between this and your code ? The first is the lack of the static on the data member. static there means that object is "static" (kind of unique/shared) for all instances of your class. Get rid of it to avoid future headaches.

The constructor has become private, this tells any user, there should be an alternative way to construct the object.

The alternative way to construct the object is the static function, which can invoke the private constructor (because they're in the same classe)  and can access any datamember of the class itself.

Now whenever you need to allocate an InQueue, you just use the static factory.

```
InQueue myQueue = InQueue.newInputQueue(someArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add another constructor to your InQueue class that converts the array to a LinkedList. Something like:

```java
public InQueue(String[] inputArr) {
  q = new LinkedList<> (Arrays.asList(inputArr));
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the method you already have and reassign like:

```java
String[] inputArr = {"id", "+", "id", "*", "id"};
InQueue inQueue = new InQueue();
inQueue = inQueue.newInputQueue(inputArr);
```

Comment: That didn't work for me because I can't put type String[] in InQueue